# Compose URL POST parameters to filter entries by category?

Tags: templating, url, request, category, post

How do you update an URL with new params?

I'm working on a search / filter entries page. I have multiple menu lists with categories in it. Like this:

**Size:**
Small
Medium
Large

**Color:**
Blue
Red
White
Yellow

So if the URL is `product?size=m` and I click on a link "Size → Large" then the URL needs to update to `product?size=m,l`. Click again on "Large" the `l` value of the sizes parameter needs to delete.

If I then click on "Color → Red" the URL must be `product?size=m,l&color=red`.

Comment: So you actually want to know how to compose the parameters and not how you "update an URL".

Comment: :-) yes. Sorry, my english isn't good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd [split the parameter string](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html) into an array and then loop through the categories and use a conditional to check if the value already exists in the parameter. It's not so easy to describe in detail, that's why I added lots of comments to the code (untested!).

To work in your other parameters (size, etc.), simply add them to your links exactly how [`craft.request.getParam()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getParam) returns them. Conditionally skip the output completely if the param is empty.

```
{# Get the parameter (e.g. 'red,blue,black') #}
{% set currentParam = craft.request.getParam('color') %}

{# Split the parameter string #}
{% set arrCurrentParam = currentParam|split(',') %}

{# Loop through categories to output the links #}
{% for catOut in categories %}

    {# Define newParam var before loop #}
    {% set newParam = '' %}

    {# Loop through categories to compose the new parameter #}
    {% for catComp in categories %}

        {# Check if changes could happen in this loop #}
        {% if catOut.slug == catComp.slug %}

            {# Add category if it was currently NOT selected #}
            {% if catComp.slug not in arrCurrentParam %}
                {% set newParam = newParam ~ ',' ~ catComp.slug %}
            {% endif %}

        {% else %}

            {# Add category if it was already selected #}
            {% if catComp.slug in arrCurrentParam %}
                {% set newParam = newParam ~ ',' ~ catComp.slug %}
            {% endif %}

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

    {# Remove leading comma #}
    {% set newParam = newParam|slice(1) %}

    {# Conditionally add param to link output #}
    <a href="product?{{ newParam ? 'color=' ~ newParam }}">{{ category.slug }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you made my day!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help, @Johannes. It was a challenge to think that one through though! But yeah, I'm sure I need something similar sooner or later, so it was definitely worth it :)

Comment: I think more crafters need this too. Thank you again!